# VSCode rename ruins indentation

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode for a Flow project, although I'm not convinced the issue is related to Flow itself. When I rename a variable in VSCode (F2), it gets correctly renamed in multiple files. But with it, all the indentation in a given class/region gets reformatted into a format inconsistent with the rest of my code. It changes indentation from 4 to 2 spaces (and yes, I know that's what React community uses, but I'm not writing React), and separates things that used to be one line into multiple lines. It's almost as if someone ran prettier with misconfigured settings on part of my project.

In my settings, I have tab set to 4 spaces, so I have no idea where these preferences are even coming from. Can I disable this "feature"? I do want to rename my variables easily but I don't want it to touch my code formatting.

Comment: Why not set-up prettier, configured to your specific prefs? There's always something that messes up formatting, so taking the time to confgure formatting is a worthwhile invesment.

Comment: This seems like a rogue feature/setting that I want to disable. The ideal fix isn't to stack more "features" on top to cancel it out. As good as Prettier is, it's not going to fix the problem, simply mask it.